# upload doc on dropbox how to get url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to get URL uploaded doc on drop box and how to store this URL our data base.

This is the code :

```
def passport_upload 
        app_key = ENV['APP_DROPBOX_APP_KEY_DEVELOPMENT'] 
        app_secret = ENV['APP_DROPBOX_APP_SECRET_DEVELOPMENT']  
        flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new(app_key, app_secret)
        authorize_url = flow.start()
        client=DropboxClient.new(ENV['APP_DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN_DEVELOPMENT'])
        file = open(params[:doc])
        file_name = params[:doc].original_filename 
        response = client.put_file(file_name, file)
  end
```

Comment: What's the output of `response`?

Comment: response:   {
    "revision": 25,
    "bytes": 10703,
    "thumb_exists": true,
    "rev": "195b0ccdff",
    "modified": "Wed, 09 Aug 2017 12:49:22 +0000",
    "mime_type": "image/png",
    "path": "/favicon (5).png",
    "is_dir": false,
    "size": "10.5 KB",
    "root": "app_folder",
    "client_mtime": "Wed, 09 Aug 2017 12:49:22 +0000",
    "icon": "page_white_picture"
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL to retrieve it using authorized access, you should appending the path returned in the metadata response to https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto/ (per https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files-GET).

If you want to publicly share it and get a public URL you will have to 
 make a call to share it (per https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares)

```
client.shares(response.path)
```